# Обработка рядков и символов. Вывод имя, фамилии, отчества студентов

Tags: c++, обработка

Входной файл сохраняет следующую информацию о студентах: <Фамилия>, <имя>, <отчество>, <год рождения>, <курс>, <пол>; причем фамилия, имя и отчество имеют не более 12 символов, пол - указывается символами М и Ж, год рождения - целое из 4 цифр, курс - целое от 1 до 5. Данные по студентам отделяются знаком «;».

Текст входного файла: Фазаров,Андрей,Филипов,1998,4,М;Фазарова,Анна,Филиповна,1998,4,Ж;Фазаров,Андрей,Филипов,1998,4,М;Фазарова,Анна,Филиповна,1998,4,Ж;

**Имеется вот такой код:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char str[256];
    cout << "Содержание файла input.txt: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
        char surname[12];
        char firstname[12];
        char middlename[12];
        int year;
        int course;
        char gender[12];
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    cout << "Список студентов:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fin.getline(str, 256, ';');
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Какой-то список: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        fin.getline(surname, 256, ',');
        fin.getline(firstname, 256, ',');
        cout << surname << endl;
    }
}
```

Вот что выводит данная программа:
[image: Фото]

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как обращаться в программе отдельно к каждому значению студента (имя,фамилия,отчество,год рождения,курс,пол). Уже пару часов просидел - ничего не понимаю. Мне нужно найти наиболее распространенное женское имя из списка. 
Буду очень благодарен, если объясните хотя-бы как обращаться к каждому из значений.

Comment: используйте struct для группировки переменных, в вашем случае struct student; должна хранить имя фамилию и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал уже так. Но я не знаю как использовать getline со структурой. Буду благодарен, если объясните.

Comment: считывайте по одному элементу, появляется запятая начинаете записывать в следующее поле структуры, появляется точка с запятой начинаете записывать в след. элемент вектора (если в векторе будете хранить студентов) следующего студента и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Временная переменная для хранения все строки
    string temp;

    //считываем файл
    ifstream fin("main.txt");

    //создаем вектор строк
    vector <string> word;

    //пока есть что читать в файле
    while (fin >> temp)
    {
        //Переменные для определения длины слова
        int nachalo = 0, konec=0;

        //проходим считаную строку по буквенно
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        {
            //если нашли ','
            if (temp[i] == ',')
            {
                //создаем новую переменную строку
                string slovo;
                //конец слова
                konec = i;
                //проходим по слову
                for (; nachalo < konec;)
                {
                    //добавляем к новому слову по букве со сторки
                    slovo += temp[nachalo];
                    //увеличиваем переменую что бы все работала)))))
                    ++nachalo;
                }
                //новоле слово начинается с конце последнего +1 (запятая)
                nachalo = i + 1;
                //добовляем созданое слово в вектор
                word.push_back(slovo);
            } 
        }
    }   

    //просто выводим все что есть в векторе
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << word[i] << " | ";
    }

 return 0;
}
```

содержимое текстового файла

```
main,function,create,disable,
too,up,down,dota,
```

Суть всего в том, что файл считывается по строчно, каждую считанную строку разирает по слову, каждое слово суется в вектор.

Можно сделать структуру, вектор из структуры. и потом мравнивать только именна которые относятся к полу "Ж"

Не брасайте в меня сразу камни) если автор не доделает, ночью напишу полностью готовый код. Который будет слово добовлять в структуру, а готовую структуру в вектор.

Лучше бы взяли меня в ученики)

Answer (score -1):

У вас данные не записываются в память программы. Поэтому вы не можете толком работать с данными. Я бы на вашем месте использовал бы вектор, который хранил бы в себе строки с даными о каждом студента и потом бы эти данные сравнивал в цикле. Если до обеда вам более конкретно не помогут, напишу полный ответ.

Я могу ошибаться, я плюсы изучаю толь 4-5 месяцев)

Answer (score -1):

Вам заранее известно количество студентов, и если вы не можете пользоваться векторами, это вас избавляет от лишнего кода для нахождения количеств студентов. Т.е. у вас есть:

```
const int N = 4;
```

ваши массивы для имен могут содержать(по заданию) и `12` символов, не считая символ `'\0'` год состоит из четырех символов, курс _ один символ и пол _ один символ, поэтому ваши объявления должны выглядеть:

```
char surname[13];
char firstname[13];
char middlename[13];
char year[5];
char course;
char gender;
```

Теперь вам нужен массив(контейнер), куда вы запишете имена студенток, чтобы потом определить какие чаще встречаются:

```
char* names[N]{0};  //имена студенток
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fin >> surname >> firstname >> middlename
        >> year >> course >> gender;
    fin.ignore(); //игнорируем символ разделитель
    if(gender == 'ж') //если это студентка
       names[k++] = firstname;         
}
```

Дело в том, что вам нужны только имена, поэтому использование `getline` больше будет мешать, чем помогать...

Теперь в массиве  записаны все имена женского пола(количество == k). Вам остается лишь найти имена, которые повторяются чаще. Вот самый примитивный  способ:

```
int count[N]{};
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < k; ++j)
        if (names[i] && names[i] == names[j]) {
            ++count[i];
        }
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    if (max < count[i])
        max = i;

cout << "наиболее часто встречается имя: " << names[max];
```

Comment: Мешанина нотаций = и {}

Comment: @Andrey,  вместо того, чтобы стараться помочь людям и сайту, и, главное, себя, вы стараетесь проявить личные отношения тут. Я чувствую, что из за вашего поведения скоро вас забанят...

Comment: Ваши слова никак не меняют ситуацию с мешаниной нотаций в Вашем коде. Видно - или торопитесь, или опыта маловато, ничего - научитесь со временем кодстайлу

Comment: @Andrey, любая наша беседа окончательно и безповоротно закончена. Больше не старайтесь писать мне что либо. Можете ставить свои минусы под всеми моими ответами, но от этого мне не холодно, мне холодно иметь отношение с такими как ты, еще несозревшим и умничающим парнем, не умеющим уважать других. Все, точка. P. S. И самое плохое, что вы в основном говорите именно глупости, к тому же вредите сайту своим поведением...

Comment: значит опыта точно мало, раз психанули при первом обсуждении кода. На работу я бы Вас не  взял)

Comment: Cпасибо, но почему-то выдает ошибку. Не знаю как исправить((

Comment: нужно указать какую ошибку, чтобы легче было помочь

Comment: https://ibb.co/7nkJLYD - вот ссылка на скрин ошибки и не выводиться имя.

Comment: я по вашему скрину ничего не увижу. Если вам самим не удается исправить ошибку, и если хотите, чтобы я вам помого, то нужно написать об ошибке прямо, так как у меня  код работает. Может у вас отсутствует символ разделитель, и тогда нужно убрать из кода    fin.ignore();

Comment: если имена разделены только запятыми, то читать нужно : fin.getline(surname, 12, ',');  fin.getline(name, 12, ',');  и т.д. вместо  fin >> surname >> firstname >> middlename
        >> year .  В конце концов файл ваш, вы знаете что там записано и вы должны знать что и как читать.